# How to get specific element in a XDcoument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have a xml structure like that

```
<A>
  <B>
     <C></C>
  </B>
  <C></C>
</A>
```

I want to get only the node (A > C). I try with Linq-to-Xml

```
XDocument.Descendants(namespace + "A").Descendants(namespace + "C")
```

But the result will return 2 nodes (A > C) and (A > B > C) instead of what I want that only node (A > C).
How can I do that ?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.Descendants` will get **all** descendants of a node that match the `XName`, in other words, it traverses the tree, looking for all nodes that match that `XName`. If you're looking for a **direct child** of a node (in your case, the root), try to iterate over its [`.Elements`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.elements?view=netframework-4.8) and grab the ones you want - these will only be direct children.

If you know there is only one child node with the `XName` you want, you can use the [`.Element(XName)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_Linq_XContainer_Element_System_Xml_Linq_XName_) method to get just that element.

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse("<A><B><C>ABC</C></B><C>AC</C></A>");
var resultsAC = doc.Element("A").Element("C");
```